# boolean function that checks whether a string contains a left angle bracket "<" in C++

Tags: c++, string, iteration

```
bool isLangle(string);
int main()
{
    string urstr;
    cout <<"enter any str "<<endl;
    cin>>urstr;
    cout<<isLangle(urstr)<<endl;
    return 0;
}

bool isLangle(string str){
    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == '<')
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

/*I am iterating through a html line but the function only checks for the first char and returns. I expect it to output true when I input "silver<" or any other string that contains left angle brackets
*/

Comment: So don't return when it's not found...

Comment: `return false` **outside** the `for` loop!!!

Comment: As a side-note I don't know why the OP was downvoted. As far as SO questions go: they have a small reproducible example, they showed their attempt, stated the problem, and the desired behavior. Questions don't come more clean-cut than that. Was it a simple answer? Yes, but it may help others in the future.

Comment: Why the downvoting? Isn't it obvious I'm a beginner and trying to learn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `return false;` outside of the loop:

```
bool isLangle(string str) {
    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == '<')
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You could look at the standard [`string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) function too:

```
bool isLangle(string str) { // or, better, const string&, see @Cyber's answer
    size_t pos = str.find('<');
    return (pos != string::npos);
}
```

Comment: while using string::find is arguably more appropriate, I think the first solution more clearly addresses the fundamental problem the OP had with the early return.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `string::find` to search for that character. If it was not found, it will return `string::npos`

```
bool isLangle(std::string const& str)
{
    std::size_t found = str.find("<");
    return found != std::string::npos;
}
```

Comment: Also consider making `str` a `const&`.